# Javascript: TypeError: ... is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, typeerror

I have a TypeError problem:

```
function artist(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.albums = new Array();

    this.addAlbum = function(albumName) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.albums.length; i++) {
            if (this.albums[i].name == albumName) {
                return this.albums[i];
            }
        }

        var album = new album(albumName);
        this.albums.push(album);

        return album;
    }
}

function album(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.songs = new Array();
    this.picture = null;

    this.addSong = function(songName, track) {
        var newSong = new songName(songName, track);
        this.songs.push(newSong);

        return newSong;
    }
}
```

gives the following error:

`TypeError: album is not a constructor`

I can't find the problem. I read a lot of other posts, but I could not find a similar problem. Could it be that it's not allowed to create an object in another object? How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 42):

This line

```
var album = new album(albumName);
```

shadows the external `album` function. So yes, `album` isn't a constructor inside the function. To be more precise it's `undefined` at this point.

To avoid this kind of problem, I'd suggest naming your "classes" starting with an uppercase :

```
function Album(name) {
```

More generally I'd suggest to follow [the Google style guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml#Naming) when in doubt.

Comment: It's equivalent to `var album; album =  new album(albumName);`. That should make it more obvious.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thanks also for your help! I wrote "var album; album = new Album(albumName);" => but without success

Comment: Thanks that helped me out of bind. Nice explanation @dystroy.