# Knockout reference/value copy between arrays

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
var card = function (item, groupMembers, removeCallback) {
    ...
    self.members = ko.observableArray(assignMembers(item.Members));
    ...
    function assignMembers(members) {
        var memberList = [];
        if (groupMembers !== "undefined" && groupMembers !== null) {
            //memberList = groupMembers.slice(0); // copy of group member list
            // control check to make sure we copied groupMembers correctly
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(groupMembers, function (member) {
                memberList.push(new member({ UserId: member.id, Name: member.name, Avatar: member.avatar }));
                console.log('Member: ', member.id, ' Checked: ', member.isChecked());
            });

            if (members !== "" && members !== null) {
                var memberIdList = members.split(',');
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(memberList, function (member) {
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(memberIdList, function (memberId) {
                        if (member.id === parseInt(memberId, 10)) {
                            member.isChecked(true);
                            // print members that matched
                            console.log('Card: ', item.CardId, ' Member: ', member.id, ' Checked: ', member.isChecked());
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            // control check to make sure things were assigned correctly
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(memberList, function (member) {
                console.log('Member: ', member.id, ' Checked: ', member.isChecked());
            });
            console.log(''); // spacer
            return memberList;
        }
        return memberList;
    }
    ...
}
```

For the most part I am trying to make a copy (value copy) of `groupMembers` array which was passed into this model. The reason for that is in the middle of the function. I am checking a comma separated list of references which were also passed into this model to mark members that were previously assigned to this card.

I've tried a few options

```
memberList = groupMembers;
memberList = groupMembers.slice(0);
```

all leading to what I believe is a reference copy. Meaning as I do changes to `memberList` array it actually changes `groupMembers` which is not good.

So if you imagine this is done for every card that gets instantiated. The result in the console window looks something like this:

```
// Card #1: initial memberList data
Member: 2 Checked: false
Member: 3 Checked: false
Member: 4 Checked: false
Member: 6 Checked: false

// Card #1: middle assignment
Card: 1004 Member: 3 Checked: true
Card: 1004 Member: 4 Checked: true

// Card #1: final memberList check
Member: 2 Checked: false
Member: 3 Checked: true
Member: 4 Checked: true
Member: 6 Checked: false
```

First card no probs.

```
// Card #2: initial memberList data
Member: 2 Checked: false
Member: 3 Checked: true
Member: 4 Checked: true
Member: 6 Checked: false

// Card #2: final memberList check
Member: 2 Checked: false
Member: 3 Checked: true
Member: 4 Checked: true
Member: 6 Checked: false
```

However second card demonstrates that code is working on the previous result.

```
// Card #3: initial memberList data
Member: 2 Checked: false
Member: 3 Checked: true
Member: 4 Checked: true
Member: 6 Checked: false

// Card #3: final memberList check
Member: 2 Checked: false
Member: 3 Checked: true
Member: 4 Checked: true
Member: 6 Checked: false
```

Third card same story.

```
// Card #4: initial memberList data
Member: 2 Checked: false
Member: 3 Checked: true
Member: 4 Checked: true
Member: 6 Checked: false

// Card #4: middle assignment
Card: 1002 Member: 2 Checked: true
Card: 1002 Member: 6 Checked: true

// Card #4: final memberList check
Member: 2 Checked: true
Member: 3 Checked: true
Member: 4 Checked: true
Member: 6 Checked: true
```

Fourth card no different but this time we had to check members with 2 and 6 references.

```
// Card #5: initial memberList data
Member: 2 Checked: true
Member: 3 Checked: true
Member: 4 Checked: true
Member: 6 Checked: true

// Card #5: middle assignment
Card: 1003 Member: 6 Checked: true

// Card #5: final memberList check
Member: 2 Checked: true
Member: 3 Checked: true
Member: 4 Checked: true
Member: 6 Checked: true
```

As you can see no the results I am after. Hence the value copy.

Despite my best efforts I run into a corner and I resorted to manually re-creating the array only to be greeted by:

```
TypeError: member is not a constructor
memberList.push(new member({UserId:member.id,Name:member.name,Avatar:member.avat...
```

error.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

#### update

Updated [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/88rafcfk/16) that I started working from.

You will notice that `groupMembers` are not actually being passed in correctly because my code looks different now and I am working on this to replicate the issue. Sorry about that.

#### update

I've been converting it a bit more. But it just keeps biting at my patience [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/88rafcfk/19/).

Comment: It might be useful if you can trim down the code to produce a runnable example of the issue.

Comment: Link is broken and I can't edit it (min 6 chars neede) http://jsfiddle.net/88rafcfk/16/] (square bracket at the end)

Comment: OMG! I didn't notice that the link was busted.

Comment: Hrm, not sure what is going on with the link there. Something not parsing right.

Comment: I fixed the links. Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is just to deep copy the data, I would go with something like the below example

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myModel);
var copiedData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: That would have also worked if I wasn't getting that TypeError.

Comment: Shouldn't that be

memberList.push(new Member(member.id,member.name,member.avatar))

I also changed the casing of the member=>Member.

Comment: I am sorry I probably should have pointed this out earlier but ``var member = function (item) {...}`` is definition for member class.

Comment: It took me a while to figure ```member=>Member`` out well till I stumbled on an explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008793/javascript-typeerror-is-not-a-constructor). So I renamed my model too ``var Member = function (item) {...}`` and all became bright again. I also didn't need to deep copy ``groupMembers`` array as I actually just stuffed it into each card before all my lists and cards were initialised. So instead I ended up with two data parameters? ``members=[]`` and ``Members=""``.