# Why Does This Typescript Output "[Class] is not a constructor."?

Tags: typescript

I'm working in typescript 1.5 in visual studio. I have a main class called app.ts, and another called FizzBuzzManager.ts. I can't figure out what is wrong with this code, but it outputs the error, "TypeError: jim.FizzBuzzManager is not a constructor".

***app.ts***

```
 namespace jim {
    class Greeter {
        element: HTMLElement;
        span: HTMLElement;
        timerToken: number;

        constructor() {
            window.console.log("constructing Greeter.");
            this.init();
        }

        private init() {
            window.console.log("Calling init.");
            var _fizzBuzzManager: any = new jim.FizzBuzzManager();
    }

}

    window.onload = () => {
        window.console.log("Hello")
        var greeter = new Greeter();

};
```

***FizzBuzzManager.ts***

```
namespace jim {

export class FizzBuzzManager {

    constructor() {
        window.console.log("Making a FizzBuzzManager.");
    }

    public myThing: String = "Hi";

    public fizzBuzz2() {
        window.console.log("fizzbuzzing2 " + this.myThing);
    }

}

export function fizzBuzz() {
    window.console.log("export function fizzbuzz");
}

}
```

The output when looking at the compiled output in a browser is this:

```
Hello                                                  app.js:15:9 
constructing Greeter.                                  app.js:5:13 
Calling init.                                          app.js:9:13 
TypeError: jim.FizzBuzzManager is not a constructor    app.js:10:36
```

Comment: what version of es are you transpiling to?

Comment: Please add your transpiled script (i.e. the `.js` file used by your browser).

Comment: Target javascript version is ES5.

Comment: It is working fine in ES5 for me... But I am getting the "not a constructor" error in ES6... But how far is the namespace usage good?

Comment: I have the same problems with typescript.  I inherit old projects that use different flavors of exports/require and they seem to only work with a very specific set of compile options.  It's very difficult to reverse engineer by looking at old typescript what the exact options are needed to compile it.

Answer (score 27):

> TypeError: jim.FizzBuzzManager is not a constructor

This is a common error when you use `--out` : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/outfile

**You are responsible for loading the files in the right order**. Don't use out and use external modules

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't loading things in the correct order. That was my issue with this error.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: ...loading and exporting in the right order! Thanks! :)

Comment: what is `--out`? I'm not using this and I'm getting this behavior error.

Answer (score 19):

When migrating from plain ES6 / Node.js using `module.exports`/`require()` it often happens to me that I forget to remove the old `module.exports = <class>` which also causes this error.

Comment: Awww, snap. I spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out. This was it! Never scrolled down to the end of the file. Lol. You'd think maybe tsc would complain/warn if a .ts file had a "module.exports = " in it perhaps. THANKYOU.

Comment: exactly the same here as the poster abover. MANY THANKS!

Comment: You may also be able to solve the problem by adding `"esModuleInterop": true` to your `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 12):

I came upon this question after googling "typescript is not a constructor". Unfortunately, these answers did not resolve my problem. I eventually found the solution, so I am posting it here for posterity.

**Problem**

I defined the following TypeScript class:

```
module mymodule {
    export class myclass {
        addDocuments(parentId: string) {
        // Code removed for brevity...
        }
    }
}
```

I then called the class in a separate module:

```
module mymodule.test {

    var myClass = new mymodule.myclass();

    export function initialize(): void {
        myClass.addDocuments("test123");
    }
}
```

After compiling and while attempting to load the page that executes the resulting Javascript, the page wouldn't load properly and I saw the following JS exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: mymodule.myclass is not a constructor

**Solution**

A fellow developer was kind enough to point out that I needed to move the instantiation of the object inside of my function. So now my instantiation code looks like this and it works as it should:

```
module mymodule.test {

    var myClass: mymodule.myclass;

    export function initialize(): void {
        myClass = new mymodule.myclass();
        myClass.addDocuments("test123");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was just circular dependencies. Take a look at that because this one is hard to catch

Comment: If this error "suddenly" happens and the constructor was working correctly beforehand, this is most likely due to a new import causing a circular dependency. I was constructing an object at the top level of a module in a circular dependency with the declaration of the class.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error `my_imported_module_1.MyModule is not a constructor`.

I was using the approach when I got this error:
`import { MyModule } from 'my-module-sdk';`

but I got it to work when I changed it to this approach:
`const MyModule = require('my-module-sdk');`

In my tsconfig.json, I have "target" set to "es5", and tried changing it "es6" and that still didn't help.

Here are some of my other tsconfig options:

```
"target": "es5",
"module": "esnext",
"declaration": true,
"rootDir": "./src",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017", "es2018", "es2019", 
"es2020"],
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"allowJs": false
```

Answer (score 5):

It might be helpful to think about it as if you were writing the code in JavaScript directly.  I came across this question because I got the same error in an Angular 2 test spec written in TypeScript.  After thinking about it based on the answers above, I realized that JavaScript would have no idea what my equivalent to your BuzzFeed class was because it was at the bottom of the file.

I moved the class up to the top of the file before my first describe statement and everything works.  Thought this might help others like myself.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that class definition is declared before its usage. That was the solution for my problem.

**Correct:**

```
class Foo {...}
...
const foo = new Foo();
```

**Incorrect:**

```
const foo = new Foo();
...
class Foo {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

Which typescript version do you use?

There is a Bug in tsc 1.8.10:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8910

Answer (score 3):

This error message means that `[Class]` is not initialized by the time a call to its constructor is made.

[Unlike functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting), classes are not “hoisted” to the top of the scope they are declared in. Whenever code uses a class that is declared later (i.e. down below in the file), this error appears.

Solution: reorganize your code so that call sites for a class appear below that class' definition in the source code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're doing:

```
export class Something
```

Change it to this and it will work

```
export default class Something
```

Comment: *why* does this matter?

Comment: this helped with the issue I had, not adding it means you have more than one class in that file and you are trying to call one of them

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as you import it correctly, if you are using default exports, then you should be importing it this way: `import Something from 'lib'` for non-default export, we simply need braces: `import { Something } from 'lib'`. I don't think that it's error related

Comment: in my case I had two classes in one file and an import `import { ClazzName } from 'lib'` and still getting the error; after splitting into multiple files OR adding default to one of the classes - it solved the problem; I'm using yarn workspaces if this makes any difference and I got a feeling it does 

Answer (score 2):

I tried to repeat your problem and I did not find any error:

**app.ts**

```
namespace jim {
    class Greeter {
        element: HTMLElement;
        span: HTMLElement;
        timerToken: number;

        constructor() {
            window.console.log("constructing Greeter.");
            this.init();
        }

        private init() {
            window.console.log("Calling init.");
            var _fizzBuzzManager: any = new jim.FizzBuzzManager();
        }

    }

    window.onload = () => {
        window.console.log("Hello")
        var greeter = new Greeter();

    };
}
```

**FizzBuzzManager.ts**

```
namespace jim {

export class FizzBuzzManager {

    constructor() {
        window.console.log("Making a FizzBuzzManager.");
    }

    public myThing: String = "Hi";

    public fizzBuzz2() {
        window.console.log("fizzbuzzing2 " + this.myThing);
    }

}

export function fizzBuzz() {
    window.console.log("export function fizzbuzz");
}

}
```

Then

```
c:\Work\TypeScript-playground>node_modules\.bin\tsc --out app.js app.ts FizzBuzzManager.ts
```

and compiled app.js file looks like this:

```
var jim;
(function (jim) {
    var Greeter = (function () {
        function Greeter() {
            window.console.log("constructing Greeter.");
            this.init();
        }
        Greeter.prototype.init = function () {
            window.console.log("Calling init.");
            var _fizzBuzzManager = new jim.FizzBuzzManager();
        };
        return Greeter;
    })();
    window.onload = function () {
        window.console.log("Hello");
        var greeter = new Greeter();
    };
})(jim || (jim = {}));
var jim;
(function (jim) {
    var FizzBuzzManager = (function () {
        function FizzBuzzManager() {
            this.myThing = "Hi";
            window.console.log("Making a FizzBuzzManager.");
        }
        FizzBuzzManager.prototype.fizzBuzz2 = function () {
            window.console.log("fizzbuzzing2 " + this.myThing);
        };
        return FizzBuzzManager;
    })();
    jim.FizzBuzzManager = FizzBuzzManager;
    function fizzBuzz() {
        window.console.log("export function fizzbuzz");
    }
    jim.fizzBuzz = fizzBuzz;
})(jim || (jim = {}));
```

Chrome browser reports in its console:

```
app.js:15 Hello
app.js:5 constructing Greeter.
app.js:9 Calling init.
app.js:24 Making a FizzBuzzManager.
```

---

There is a good explanation of the error you are getting here: [Javascript: TypeError: ... is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008793/javascript-typeerror-is-not-a-constructor) (not that it reveals the origin of the problem but you may see the problem in your transpiled code.)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find the tsc file path?

Comment: I installed it via `npm install typescript@1.5` in my command line

Comment: This install TypeScript in your current working directory, so you can try it out very easily.

Comment: I installed it from npm, but I'm still getting the error. Are you putting this compiler argument in the textfield labeled "conditional compilation symbols" under project->Properties->Build?

Comment: Even when I enter the whole line in command line, it says, "C:\Users\James\nodey-node\tsc is not a recognized internal or external command, operable program, or batch file"

Comment: No, I do it simply in `cmd` (win+R -> cmd) tool because it makes easier to locate the source of problem and in your case it seems there is a problem in VS settings

Comment: Look at my last comment. It's not recognized in cmd either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99625/discussion-between-martin-vseticka-and-jim).

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, the problem could also be if the constructor expects parameters
and you are giving no parameters or a different number of parameters.
This is because for Javascript a function with a different number of parameters is a different function.

A simple solution could be to add default parameters in the constructor.

My example was like this:

SegmentsQueryBuilder.ts

```
class SegmentsQueryBuilder {
  //...
  constructor(scoping) {
    //...
  }
//...
}
```

segments.query.builder.test.ts

```
describe('Segment base query', () => {
  test('should create segment select with default fields', () => {
    const segmentQueryBuilder = new SegmentQueryBuilder() //ERROR HERE
//...
```

The solution here was either to use default parameter in the constructor or to pass the scoping object in the usage of the constructor

Comment: I'll add that it can also happen if the constructor is outright missing. This happened to me when a third party library was using another third party library (AWS CDK) that had moved stuff around between libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Using `export = Something` instead of `export class Something` solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the problem when I used babel with preset-env to compile TS-sources.

Works:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/typescript"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ],
    "ignore": ["node_modules", "src/test"]
}
```

Wrong:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/typescript",
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": [
                        "last 2 Chrome versions",
                        "last 1 Safari versions",
                        "last 1 Firefox versions"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ],
    "env": {
        "node": {
            "presets": [
                [
                    "@babel/preset-env",
                    {
                        "targets": {
                            "esmodules": true,
                            "node": "current"
                        },
                        "modules": "auto"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    },

    "ignore": ["node_modules", "src/test"]
}
```

Comment: Nice, that helped me fixing my error. But how do we use babel-env then?

Answer (score 1):

at first, make sure that use

```
/// <reference path = "FizzBuzzManager.ts" />
```

to refrence code to another .ts file at typescript root file

to compile typescript files that exist in different file.ts use this command

> tsc --out app.js app.ts

because this command converts all typescript files into app.js

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, apart from `export default class Something`
I created a separate file called `something.ts` then another file `index.ts`
in the `someting.ts` file
I had

```
export default class Something {}
```

then in `index.ts`
I wrote

```
import { Something } from './something';
export = Something;
```

after that I could import as (For Typescript)

```
import Something from './';
```

and as (For Javascript)

```
const Something = require('./');
```

Answer (score 0):

With JetBrains WebStorm, it's possible to get this error in your tests even if you have fixed a problem with imports in the code itself.

e.g. the following fix:

```
// import { Foo } from '@foo/bar';

import Foo = require('@foo/bar);
```

solved the issue, but it was necessary to run `npm run compile` or `npm run test` afterwards.

Then running the tests in WebStorm worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Clear the output directory

## Explanation

In my case, this problem occurred after I had moved `src/email.ts` to `src/email/index.ts`. TSC didn't remove `lib/email.ts`, causing the class I had defined in the new location not to be available.