# Typescript error "class is not a constructor"

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am running the following typescript code in the ES6 target environment and it says that "Cars is not a constructor"

I have followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581714/why-does-this-typescript-output-class-is-not-a-constructor) and tried changing the target environment to ES5. It is working fine. Can some one tell why it is not working for target ES6.

Here is my TypeScript code:

```
export class Cars {
    constructor(public len: number,public wid: number) { }
}

export function getSize(): Cars {
    return new Cars(20, 30);
};
```

Error is "Cars is not a constructor" in the function getSize.

By the way I am trying to load all the files with Systemjs.

By the way I am getting the error in the browser........ Not while compiling it...

Here is the compiled code of the above typescript....

```
System.register([], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var Cars;
    function getSize() {
        return new Cars(20, 30);
    }
    exports_1("getSize", getSize);
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            class Cars {
                constructor(len, wid) {
                    this.len = len;
                    this.wid = wid;
                }
            }
            ;
            exports_1("Cars", Cars);
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=Cars.js.map
```

Comment: basarat's answer in the linked question suggests not using `--out`. Are you using `--out`?

Comment: Nope... I am not using any such... By the way I am getting the error in the browser........ Not while compiling it...

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula: Then please also post the compiled code that throws the error

Comment: @Bergi: I posted the compiled code... I am using the latest typescript version... And I read in the following link https://www.sitepoint.com/the-es6-conundrum/ where it says ES6 is not yet supported by the browsers... Is that the reason for the code not working in the browser?

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula: No problem with ES6 here. It's really just that the compiler is putting out invalid code here that cannot work - it's a TS bug, as Arnavion correctly identified. You should accept his answer.

Comment: @Bergi: I compiled the code as Arnavion said... But it still generates the same code as above...

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula: But have you updated tsc to the latest version? Possibly even a nightly?

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah my tsc is the latest version.. I just installed typescript and compiled it again... Still the same error...

Comment: As I said, it's fixed in master. The latest release of TS (currently 1.8.10) has the bug. To test the fix you'll need a nightly version that you can install with `npm install typescript@next`.

Note that this version is only for testing and should not be used for production code. To solve your problem I recommend to just compile to ES5 instead.

Comment: @Arnavion: Sure.... Thanks very much....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Copying my post from [the GH issue you opened.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8910))

This is a bug in TS 1.8.10 and fixed in master.

`tsc -t es6 ./foo.ts -m system`

in 1.8.10 gives:

```js
System.register([], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var Cars;
    function getSize() {
        return new Cars(20, 30);
    }
    exports_1("getSize", getSize);
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            class Cars { // (1)
                constructor(len, wid) {
                    this.len = len;
                    this.wid = wid;
                }
            }
            exports_1("Cars", Cars);
        }
    }
});
```

So `getSize` ends up using the `var Cars` which is `undefined`.

In master the output for `(1)` is instead `Cars = class Cars {` so it assigns to the `var Cars` and `getSize()` works.

Comment: I must have said it earlier... But I am facing this problem in the browser but not while compiling the typescript....

Comment: I compiled the code using the tsc -t es6 -m system... But it still gives me the same js as above...

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you don't have `.js` and `.ts` files in the same directory. This can be caused by your IDE sometimes.

Comment: I had *.json file in the same problem witch makes this problem, thanks

Comment: I had a file named `base.class.ts` and another one called `base.class` (created earlier by inadvertance). I deleted the last one and this fixed my issue.

Comment: Yay, just changed outDir in tsconfig. worked, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I think that this depends on the TypeScript version.

Please try declaring this like so:

```
class Cars {
    constructor(public len: number,public wid: number) { }
}

export function getSize(): Cars {
    return new Cars(20, 30);
};

export { Cars };
```