# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: LocationModel_1.LocationModel is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using `Ionic 2`.

I am getting this error, and I cannot figure out why. I am creating an object with a constructor, but the error states there is no constructor. Any help appreciated.

**error**

```
TypeError: LocationModel_1.LocationModel is not a constructor
var locationModel = new LocationModel_1.LocationModel();
```

**code**

```
var locationModel: LocationModel = new LocationModel();
```

**LocationModel.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class LocationModel {
    public id: number = null;
    public latitude: number = null;
    public longitude: number = null;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554119/typescript-error-class-is-not-a-constructor) says it is a bug with Typescript:

`This is a bug in TS 1.8.10 and fixed in master.`
What do I do to fix this? Do I upgrade my Typescript? How do I know what version I am using? How do I upgrade?

Comment: `npm install -g typescript`

installs `typescript@1.8.10`, so I guess this is the latest version? What do they mean it's fixed on `master`, how do I install `master`?

Comment: `npm install typescript@next` has not fixed this error.