# when keyDown 'A', I want 'C' is diplayed, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, keyboard-events

### condition

when I press 'D', I want 'X' to be displayed in inputField, not 'D'.

when I press 'ArrowDown', I want 'ArrowRight' to be triggered. not 'ArrowDown'.

using Typesript, Next

#### what I tried:

```js
const drunkenKeyboard = (e) =>{
  if(e.code === 'ArrowDown') {
    const action = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: 'ArrowLeft'});
    inputRef.current.dispatchEvent(action);
  }
}

// ...

<input onKeyDown={drunkenKeyboard} ref={inputRef}  ... />
```

but this cause type error :(

```js
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: react_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.KeyboardEvent is not a constructor
```

what should I do? any ideas?
thanks.

Comment: `but this cause type error`, make sure to include that error in the question. It's almost impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: @Olian04 thanks for your comment. I added the error message,

Comment: Perhaps you need 'new KeyboardEvent' instead of 'new keyboardEvent'?

Comment: Seems similar to this question. Do you have both js and ts files in the same folder? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40533078/12334204

Comment: @Zock77 oops. I edit the code line, but same error :(

Comment: @BrettS thanks for great suggestion. but in the same folder, there's only typescirpt files... 'index.stories.ts', 'index.tsx', 'styles.ts'.