# MarkerWithLabel is not a constructor

Tags: angular, google-maps

I used `MarkerWithLabel` but got this error:

```
the core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: markerwithlabel__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.MarkerWithLabel is not a constructor
```

Here's my code:

```js
     this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: this.latLng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        this.marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
          position: this.homeLatLng,
          map: this.map,
          draggable: true,
          raiseOnDrag: true,
          labelContent: "A",
          labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
          labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
          labelInBackground: false
        });
    
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, "click", function (e) { this.iw.open(map, this); });
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/34581714/10281456

Comment: I'm guessing you need to import or otherwise reference the code that declares what MarkerWithLabel is. E.g. if you are using npm, then `npm i @googlemaps/markerwithlabel` or if you are not using a package manager then with a script tag. See here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markerwithlabel