# Jest outputs that a class constructor is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a class called `Server` with a function `initRoutes` and a bunch of others:

```js
export class Server {
  
  app: Express;
  checklistRouter: ChecklistRouter;
  dateRouter: ChecklistRouter;
  <...>

  constructor(){
        this.app = express();
        this.checklistRouter = new ChecklistRouter(new ChecklistService(checklistDatabase));
        this.dateRouter = new DateRouter(new DateService(dateDatabase));
  }

  initRoutes() {
        this.app.use('/', this.checklistRouter.getRouter());
        this.app.use('/', this.dateRouter.getRouter());
  }

<... some other functions >
}
```

I already have jest tests written for the `Router`, `Service` and `Database` classes and they work just fine. Now I've been meaning to write a test for the `Server` class and it seems to get stuck on the `initRoutes` function. I've commented everything in the `Server` class  and then started uncommenting while running the test and it works fine until I uncomment this one function. My jest test looks like this:

```js
import { Server } from '../../src/services/server.service';

describe('Server tests', () => {
    const server = new Server();
    it('Should create "Server" instance', () => {
        expect(server).toBeInstanceOf(Server);
    });
})
```

The error is:

```bash
tests/unit/server.test.ts
  - Test suite failed to run
TypeError: server_service_1.Server is not a constructor
```

I'm completely confused by this behaviour and don't know what else to try. I've initialized and tested every other class without issues and more so, everything is working without issues when I run the server without jest.

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Does This Typescript Output "\[Class\] is not a constructor."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581714/why-does-this-typescript-output-class-is-not-a-constructor)

Comment: No, but thanks for the reply. I actually figured it out by myself after a lot of debugging. Will close this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out and the error message was just misleading. My `xxxxDatabase` classes were extending another class

```js
export class ChecklistDatabase extends Database { ... }
```

and the `Database` class itself was importing my own/the above mentioned `Server` class instead of another `Server` class, which created a cyclic dependency. I'm still not sure why only jest was complaining and with a completely different error message, but after changing the imports everything is working now.