# typescript definition constructor or function?

Tags: javascript, constructor, typescript

I am trying to create a typescript definition file for an existing javaScript library, but keep getting run time errors.

The library contains the following code:

```
/**
* Pdok namespace, will hold Api namespace
* @namespace
*/
Pdok = {};

Pdok.Api = function(config) {

/* implementation details are here... */
}
```

The javascript example code that was supplied works and contains the following line:

```
var api = new Pdok.Api(config);
```

I created a typescript definition file, and am able to compile without any problems. The definition looks like:

```
declare namespace Pdok
{
    interface configOptions {
        /* .. details .. */
    }

    class Api {
        constructor(config: configOptions);
    }
}
```

At run time, i get the following error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Pdok.Api is not a constructor

What should be in my .d.ts-file to get this working?

Comment: Curiously, [their example](http://kaart.pdok.nl/api/api-doc/symbols/src/api_js_pdok-api.js.html) shows usage as `api = Pdok.Api(config)` (no use of `new`) yet the `Api` function does look like a constructor (uses `this` a bunch and does not explicitly return anything).

Comment: Yes, i also noticed the code in the comments was different from the examples available through https://www.pdok.nl/sites/default/files/pdokkaart/pdok-kaart-source-code-20130726.zip. The examples from these files are all working. This is also the source i used for the pdok-api.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15008808/4516689 it could be that the source isn't loaded correctly.

Set a debugger; directive before your code and check to what the variable Pdok.Api is set to.

```
debugger;
var api = new Pdok.Api(config);
```

or use this

```
alert(Pdok.Api);
var api = new Pdok.Api(config);
```

it should return "function (config) { ..."

Comment: You were right. The issue was that the scripts were not loaded in the correct order.

Comment: If you create your own .d.ts maybe this link can help you. 
https://github.com/fivetran/typescript-closure-tools 
It creates .d.ts from JSDoc. Not perfect but as base for your on defintion file.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will look into this.